# Symfony 2 validateProperty: Notice: Undefined index

Tags: symfony, validation

I have a little problem with validateProperty of the validator service.

My purpose is to add a constraint on a field of my form during the process function in the handler. The problem is that I have an error that notice me that symfony can't find the index I give to the validateProperty method. However, I check the type of object give at first argument, and property with the same name that the second argument exists !

My code in the handler:

```
$regex = new Regex([
    'pattern' => '#pattern#', 
    'match' => false, 
    'message' => "Error"]);

$this->validator->validateProperty($this->form->getData(), 'content', $regex);
```

(getData() returns a Message type entity in which there is a field $content)

Do you know what is the problem ?

Thanks a lot.

Useful link: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator.html#method_validateProperty

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Hum, you should review PHP basics : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array.php</strike>

You can't declare arrays on the fly with '[' and ']'.

Third parameter of validateProperty is an array of validation groups, not the Regex itself. Leave it empty by default...

Comment: Hum, you should review PHP 5**.4** basics : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Hum, you should upgrade your PHP version ? :D